# Why is there a height difference in IE for text(fonts)

Tags: html, css

First time I've ever noticed this but is probably an easy one. How come IE and chrome give different heights to fonts? What are the best practices to combat this? This is messing up my header layout, I'm trying to get it to look the same on all browsers.

[image: Imgur]

The code to produce Img:

```
<html>
<head>    
<style>
    body{margin:0;}
    div {
        margin-top: 5px;
        font-size:16px;
    }
    .c1 {
        font-family: Arial;
        background: blue;
    }
    .c2 {
        font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode;
        background: red;
    }      
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="c1"> My Text 1 </div>
    <div class="c2"> My Text 2 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: - Additionally
Here is an image of the text laid over one another. The text height in pixels is the same in each but the problem seems to be that they don't both use the same margin/padding(whatever it is) at the top and bottom of the text.

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Try to add `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;`

Answer (score 1):

It's only because you haven't set a `font-size`, so it uses the default size of that browser. I tried the code and had the same thing, but after setting a size it didn't show up anymore.

> div {
>           margin-top: 5px;
>           font-size: 30px;
>       }

And just for your knowledge, you can use `rem` to set size by default browser size, like this:

> div {
>           margin-top: 5px;
>           font-size: 1.5 rem;
>       }

And that gives you 1.5x the default size of the browser.

**Update**

Problem seems to be in `line-height`, which you should set for the divs. It could also be the `padding` of the divs. Try setting those and I hope it helped. If not then try setting div `display: block`.

Comment: Oh I assumed they would be the same. After I added font-size:16px I'm still getting a different height.
[Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/291SXl6.png)

Comment: Is the difference in the symbols or the space above it

Comment: Yeah the space is added above and below the text but the text itself is the exact same size in px. @Marlo

Comment: In that case you should try setting `padding` and `line-height` to 0. Also, `display: block` might help.

Comment: Turns out I need to use **both** `line-height:` and `display: inline-block;` to get them to play nicely. Thanks for your help guys now I am a step closer to pixel perfection :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting defaults for the webpage?

This problem actually looks like it is line-height.
Browsers tend to render things differently from one browser to the next. Try setting defaults.

Line-height actually changes the size of the line the text sits on. Might be padding in this case...

line-height
margin
padding
font-size

Theres a lot of defaults you should/could set. This does not ensure the same look from one browser to the next. It does help alot though.

Good luck!.

Comment: Yes. font-size:14px; and line-height:14px;